# blending the indexes from 2 series into 1 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

so I start from these 2 lists:

```
import pandas as pd

cat = [4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4]
dog = [4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4]
```

I transform these to pd.Series:

```
cat = pd.Series(cat, index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'])
dog = pd.Series(dog, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

and then use them to create a DataFrame:

```
animals = pd.DataFrame([cat, dog], index = ['cat', 'dog']).transpose()
```

which generates the following DataFrame:

```
    cat dog
1   4.0 NaN
2   5.0 NaN
3   5.0 NaN
4   6.0 NaN
5   7.0 NaN
6   4.0 NaN
a   NaN 4.0
b   NaN 5.0
c   NaN 5.0
d   NaN 6.0
e   NaN 7.0
f   NaN 4.0
```

my question is: how can i blend the 2 Series so that the DataFrame uses a common index, rather than the unique indexes it gets from the Series?

output should look like:

```
    cat dog
r   4.0 4.0
f   5.0 5.0
v   5.0 5.0
d   6.0 6.0
a   7.0 7.0
h   4.0 4.0
```

Comment: So you just want to ignore the indices from the series?

Comment: I want either the dog series to use cat's indices or the animals DataFrame to generate own indices and stack the 2 series

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the desired output is, can you update the question?

Comment: yep, done, edited :)

Comment: Where do the `r f v d a h` come from? That seems completely random compared to either of the indices.

Comment: that's the point, generating random indices so that both Series can fit like desired output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, you are facing intrinsic data alignment, where pandas aligns mostly all operations based on indexes (including column headers) of a dataframe.   One way to get your desired output is to match indexing.

```
cat = [4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4]
dog = [4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 4]
cat = pd.Series(cat, index = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']).rename('cat')
dog = pd.Series(dog, index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']).rename('dog')

cat_c = cat.rename(index={c:d for c, d in zip(cat.index,dog.index)})
pd.concat([cat_c, dog], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
|    |   cat |   dog |
|----|-------|-------|
| a  |     4 |     4 |
| b  |     5 |     5 |
| c  |     5 |     5 |
| d  |     6 |     6 |
| e  |     7 |     7 |
| f  |     4 |     4 |
```

Comment: How did you get this prettyprinted table? Is there option in Pandas to print it like that?

Comment: I am using a feature in pandas 1.0.0. to_markdown() with this particular format I used `print(pd.concat([cat_c, dog], axis=1).to_markdown(tablefmt='github'))`